# Printing backslashes issue

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem with this code

```
System.out.println("\\---------------------//");
```

It does not print this

```
\\---------------------//
```

but this

```
\---------------------//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` has to be escaped. Therefore, to print two `\` you need :

```
System.out.println("\\\\---------------------//");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character needs to be escaped using another `\` character.

To print `\\` you will need to use `\\\\`.

So it should be:

```
System.out.println("\\\\---------------------//");
```